# How to make renderscript from android 4.0 as separate lib to run at android 2.x?

Tags: android, live-wallpaper, renderscript

Android 4.0 provide new renderscript API now. 
How to make renderscript from android 4.0 as separate lib to run  at android 2.x ?

Related sources:
1)The related renderscript java source can be achieved from https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/tree/master/graphics/java/android/renderscript
2) libRS.so and librs_jni.so can be achieved from any android 4.0 rom at system/lib folder

Hope someone can provide the solution to make android 4.0 renderscript as separate lib to use at android 2.x system.

llvm will build our source as bitcode.This step is ok becuase we build our project by android sdk 15. And then libbcc  will make bitcode  as  machine code. It's the problem we need your guys to help also.

Comment: One thing that will also be needed is the llvm compiler on the target for the appropriate architecture. Also, given that 4.0 supports some features of RenderScript that 3.2 doesnt, my guess is there is more to it than simply having the appropriate libraries, or Google would have done it.

Comment: @Jared  . I think llvm compiler is the problem. When we build our porject by andorid sdk 15+.It have done de compile work.

Answer (score 0):

As you point out, you are able to create the bytecode by building against SDK 15. With the way RenderScript was designed, this byte code is supposed to be universal (in theory) and then compiled for each device by a native compiler program. This compiler is tailored to the specific nuances of the device, and eventually may even support targets such as DSP and x86 architectures, not just the ARM devices that we see in most if not all mobile devices. I have no way of confirming that this will work, but if you can extract the compiler from a device that supports RenderScript using the same processor, you might be able to make it happen, although I have no idea what is required on the Android side to make this all happen.

Comment: I think i need the compiler for ARM devices only.